# Scss Scale image in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, internet-explorer-11

I have an image that is displaying fine in all browsers other than IE11. The image has the following scss:

```
 &__container {
    text-align: center;
  }

  &__logo {
    img {
      background: transparent;
      height: 13.5em;
    }
  }
```

In IE11, the bottom of the image and the right hand side of the image is cut off. I have added some custom CSS for just IE11:

```
&__logo {
    img {
      background: transparent;
      height: 13.5em;
      @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
        width: 30%;
        height: 30%;
      }
}
```

This displays the entire image but it is still much bigger than what you can see in other browsers, and also adds a padding below it. **This also prevents the `text-align:center` from working and aligns slightly off-centre towards the left.**

I've tried just removing height or just removing width but that doesn't solve it.

Any suggestions would be most helpful!

Comment: You can add snippet here not only styles but also css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, removing the `height` and adding `max-width` solved the issue.

```
&__logo {
    img {
      background: transparent;
      max-width: 16em;
    }
  }
```

If anyone knows why this is the case, please comment as it would be useful to know for the future!

Answer (score 0):

You just entered a piece of code without html without anything so I don't know if this will be a good solution. Add to img `display: block;` this should help in IE11

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
  border: 3px solid #ff0000;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  height: 13.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```